# How to detect what class is used in proxy?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, proxy, ejb

For example I have proxy that is proxing interface `CashManagment`, toString of this proxy is `somepackage.CashManagment:Stateless`. I would like to know what real classes is being used by this proxy.

I think its EJB. `CashManagment` has more than one implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` — I'm assuming that's what you're talking about — does not offer any way of discovering what the underlying proxied object is, or its class for that matter. It might be obtainable by using reflection, but that would be dependent on the runtime implementation and thus not a good idea.

If you're using Spring and its proxy mechanisms, then perhaps there is a way to obtain this.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a function getType() in the interface, which returns the type of the implementation.